# materialize header text overflow

Tags: css, materialize

I've been trying out materialize and when working on the nav bar, depending on how long the logo is, it will overflow outside the div as shown in the snippet if you were to shrink the window. How would you fix this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--Import materialize.css-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <title>Quiz Manager</title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <header>
       <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo black-text">Test Brand Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
     </header>
   </body>
```

Comment: Please look at the docs, this isn't the correct markup for the nav... the hamburger should be within it's own UL for instance.

Comment: @ProEvils I've changed it to be the one in the documentation, still doesn't work if you inspect the page and shrink it all the way down in responsive mode

Comment: I see. Materializecss got a weird way of doing things with absolute positioning.

Comment: I would just use a media query at this point and control the font-size. Seems like they're still doing the old clunky method of centering instead of using something like flex.

Answer (score 0):

***Add the following to your script:***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
```